# Codeigniter db update with where clause and custom var are not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can somebody tell me why my update did not work ?

Here are the data in my variable
$id = '1';
$table = 'tb_home_content';
$data = Array ( [title] => SLEEK DESIGN [content] => We have a sleek design which not only attractive but simple in design for our user to see. [classicon] => fa fa-clone );

Here are my model function

```
    public function updateData($table, $data)
    {
        $id = $data['id'];
        array_shift($data);

        // echo $id.'<br>';
        // echo $table.'<br>';
        // print_r($data);

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update($table, $data);

        if($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
        {
            echo "<script>";
                echo "alert('Success');";
            echo "</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>";
                echo "alert('Failed');";
            echo "</script>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error message you are getting? Are you sure the value at the position of id is the first element in the array?

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 POST admin/actioninsert 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I could echo the variable which show this $id = '1'; $table = 'tb_home_content'; $data = Array ( [title] => SLEEK DESIGN [content] => We have a sleek design which not only attractive but simple in design for our user to see. [classicon] => fa fa-clone ); but the update did not work

Comment: @user2977799 Try to echo or var_dump the error message using $this->db->error()

Comment: I could only get this result array(2) { ["code"]=> int(0) ["message"]=> string(0) "" } if i put var_dump($this->db->error()); below the code else code and give comment in where and update line.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, seems like my data are wrong. is should be class_icon in the array not classicon.